# Will an ajax request ever reach readyState 4 if a local firewall is blocking the URL requested?

Tags: javascript, ajax

It's my understanding that a local (or local network) firewall blocking a URL will prevent an Ajax request to this URL from reaching ReadyState 4. Is this correct?

Comment: Sure it can reach a `readyState` of 4, why not? That doesn't mean the `status` will be 200 obviously

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScript, I thought readystate may have not reached 4 because the firewall may have blocked requests to that server.

Comment: Sure, the firewall can block the request, but it doesn't mean the request just goes away. The request goes out, and firewall will block it, so it will respond to your JavaScript with the reason. In order to determine its successfulness, you check the `status` property. The `readyState` is to describe the state of the request - whether it's been opened, was sent, received, etc. The `status` describes the HTTP status. Try opening the URL in your browser (like via the address bar)...what do you get? A `404` error? Or some other `4XX` error? Well, that's what the `XMLHttpRequest` will respond with

Comment: @IanJones Are you asking because you are not getting a response? I just had a huge issue with ajax not returning a result. You may need to check if your server is setup for cross site scripting. Its really easy to enable but hard to diagnose. Try putting try catches around your ajax calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will.  For example, look at this code.

```
function readyStateCallback () {
  jsprint(this.readyState);
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onreadystatechange = readyStateCallback;
oReq.open("get", "http://foobarbaz.nnn", true);
oReq.send();
```

You can try it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6efd8/).  Every request triggers a ready state of 1 and 4, but not 
necessarily ready states 2 or 3.

See the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) MDN docs.

```
0   UNSENT               open() has not been called yet.
1   OPENED               send() has not been called yet.
2   HEADERS_RECEIVED     send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
3   LOADING              Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
4   DONE                 The operation is complete.
```

---

To determine if the request failed (such as being blocked by a firewall), check this.status.  For a good request this will be 200.  For a request that didn't receive a response, it will be 0.

> The status attribute must return the result of running these steps:
>
> 1. If the state is UNSENT or OPENED, return 0 and terminate these steps.
> 2. If the error flag is set, return 0 and terminate these steps.
> 3. Return the HTTP status code.
>
> <sub>Source: [W3 XMLHttpRequest::status](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-status-attribute)</sub>

Network errors are described as,

> DNS errors, TLS negotiation failure, or other type of network errors
>   It also discusses that the onreadystatechange event is to be fired in the case of an error.  The readystate will be 4.

A firewall will usually either prohibit DNS resolution or the TLS packets from being successfully sent.

Comment: How does this have anything to do with a firewall? You're just explaining how a normal AJAX request works, and using a cross-domain URL. I'd assume this is all correct, but there's nothing about firewalls here.